# 'x' and 'y' lengths differ ERROR when plotting

Tags: r

I just started using R.
I am supposed to Calculate a new variable “Vehic_vol” from the sum of “Psgr_Vol” and “Lugg_Vol” and Plot this new variable against “CITY_MPG” for the whole data set but I end up with 'x' and 'y' lengths differ ERROR! Any thoughts?

Here is what I did:

```r
Vehic_vol<-(VehicleData$Psgr_Vol + VehicleData$Lugg_Vol)
 plot (VehicleData$Vehic_vol, VehicleData$CITY_MPG)
```

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the code you provided, `Vehic_vol` is not a column of `VehicleData`. If you enter in

```
VehicleData$Vehic_vol
```

it returns

```
NULL
```

Note that `NULL` and `VehicleData$CITY_MPG` have different lengths (use `length()` to verify that).

Try this instead

```
plot (Vehic_vol, VehicleData$CITY_MPG)
```

or

```
VehicleData$Vehic_vol <- (VehicleData$Psgr_Vol + VehicleData$Lugg_Vol)
plot (VehicleData$Vehic_vol, VehicleData$CITY_MPG)
```

Comment: **General rule suggestion**: In my R code I tend to separate a _"add derived values to my dataframe"_ phase from a _"now use the extended stuff for plotting"_ phase. In this manner of working you would have written `VehicleData$Vehic_vol <- (VehicleData$Psgr_Vol + VehicleData$Lugg_Vol)` (variant 2 of above) and the subsequent `plot` command would have worked as you wanted it to as a matter of course (without straining your short term memory much).

Answer (score -2):

For Example, my dataset,

```
mod.2 <- lm(CEC ~ clay + ExchNa + ExchCa,
             data = subs.soil.data)
```

when you write a model like this and want to draw this modela plot,
`plot(mod.2$y, mod.2$fitted.values)` 
this is error "Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
'x' and 'y' lengths differ"

--First, check with length ()

```
length(mod.2$y)
[1] 0
```

As you can see, the dependent variable y is `0` in length, i.e. it doesn't exist.

Solution

`mod.2 <- lm (CEC ~ clay + ExchNa + ExchCa, data = subs.soil.data, y = TRUE, x = TRUE)`

We did not define x and y in the previous formula for mod.2, and this is the cause of the error.

```r
plot(mod.2$y, mod.2$fitted.values)
```

```
> length(mod.2$y)
[1] 146
> length(mod.2$fitted.values)
[1] 146
>
```

This problem has now disappeared.